# How to delete 1 character in SQL

Tags: sql

[image: PICTURE]

ID column has some values starting with ' and some do not. How can I use function to delete all ' in ID Column.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your attempts next time, that shows you're actually trying to achieve something on your own but here you go:

```
update <your_table> t
    -- desired columns go here
   set t.id = regexp_replace(t.id, '^''{1}', '')
    -- can be omitted if you want to scan all records
 where t.id like '''%';
```

If you want to replace all quote characters you can do this:

```
update <your_table> t
    -- desired columns go here
   set t.id = replace(t.id, '''', '')
 where t.id like '''%';
```